# Horizontal truncation of the upper signed Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, lebesgue-integral, simple-functions

> Prove or disprove that $\forall d\ge_\mathbb Z0,\forall f\colon\mathbb R^d\to[0,+\infty],$ $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\overline{\int_{\mathbb R^d}}\min(f(x),n)\,\mathrm{d}x=\overline{\int_{\mathbb R^d}}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

I tried, unsuccessfully, to prove it similar to how I proved the lower signed Lebesgue integral version.

This is from Tao's "An Introduction to Measure Theory" page 54.

**Edit 1.** The upper signed Lebesgue integral is defined as $$\overline{\int_{\mathbb R^d}}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x:=\inf _{h \geq f;\,h\text{ simple}} \operatorname{Simp} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: Could you define the upper signed Lebesgue integral? Intuitively this should be true for the Lebesgue integral since the integrand on the LHS defines a non-decreasing sequence converging to $f(x)$.

Comment: @Enforce See edit 1 for the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d:=1$. Let $f(x):=\mathbf1_{(0,1]}(x)x^{-\frac{1}2}$. Let $h\ge f;h$ simple. Then $h({\{y\in\mathbb R:f(y)>\max(h(\mathbb R)\setminus\{+\infty\})\}})=\{+\infty\}$.